# Highest dimension using custom rank and case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the highest program for a student:
Program level PhD>MA>CERT

```
Table A:
Student | Program
Student 1|A.PhD
Student 1|B.MA
Student 2|A.CERT
Student 2|B.MA

Output
Student  | Highest Program
Student 1|A.PhD
Student 2|B.MA
```

I tried assigning custom ranks to the program levels and then take the min of the rank, but I am missing something there. Can someone advise a better approach to achieve the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `coalesce()` and some cleverness:

```
select student,
       coalesce(max(case when program = 'A.PhD' then program end),
                max(case when program = 'B.MA' then program end),
                max(case when program = 'A.Cert' then program end)
               ) as highest_program
from a
group by student;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)